# Ruby: the yield inside of a block

Tags: ruby, return, yield

Here is an example of scan:

```
"abcdeabcabc".scan("a")
```

So it returns an array of 3 a's. Another example of scan:

```
"abcdeabcabc".scan("a") {|x| puts x}
```

which just output each "a", but still output an array, and this time it is actually the original string that it returns.

So from the documentation and the behavior above, the scan either returns an array (no block is given), or returns the original string before which some side-effects take place. The point is that both cases returns something.

Then what will happen if I put a "yield" inside of the block? What will be returned? Or, none? **What will be the type of the return value?**

```
"abcdeabcabc".scan("a") {|x| yield x}
```

The above will not work as Ruby complains that no block is given. Which makes some sense to me. But if it is part of a class method, say, self-implemented "each", then the following works:

```
class Test
  def my_each
    "abcdeabcabc".scan("a") {|x| yield x}
  end
end
# => :my_each

t = Test.new
# => #<Test:0x007ff00a8d79b0>

t.my_each {|x| puts "so this is #{x}"}
# it works. Outpus 3 a's then return the original string.
```

So, what is the return value of the my_each method of Test class? Is that a list of yield's or something? But as discussed before "abcdeabcabc".scan("a") {|x| yield x} segment will be complained by Ruby until a block is given. What happened internally to give the block of my_each to the segment inside of my_each implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block is passed similarly to the argument of that function. This can be specified explicitly, like so:

```rb
class Test
  def my_each(&block)
    "abcdeabcabc".scan("a") do |x|
      puts "!!! block"
      yield x
      # Could be replaced with: block.call(x)
    end
  end
end
```

Technically, it's exactly the same (`puts` put in there for clarification), its presence is not checked the way it is usually done for arguments. Should you forget to give it a block, the function will halt on the first `yield` it has to execute with exactly the same `LocalJumpError` (at least, that's what I get on Rubinius). However, notice the "!!! block" in the console before it happens.

It works like that for a reason. You could check whether your function is given a block, if it is specified explicitly as above, using `if block`, and then skip the `yield`s. A good example of that is a `content_tag` helper for Rails. Calls of this helper can be block-nested. A simplistic example:

```rb
content_tag :div do
  content_tag :div
end
```

...to produce output like:

```
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

So, the block is executed "on top" (in terms of call stack) of your method. It is called each time a `yield` happens as some sort of function call on a block. It's not accumulated anywhere to execute the block afterwards.

UPD:

The `Enumerator` returned by many `each`es is explicitly constructed by many iterators to save context of what should happen.

It could be implemented like this on `my_each`:

```rb
class Test
  def my_each(&block)
    if block
      "abcdeabcabc".scan("a") { |x| yield x }
    else
      Enumerator.new(self, :my_each)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer makes much more sense to me. At runtime the puts actually output something so it is good to know it's executed somehow, but as with other answers I am still curious about the type of the return value if no block is given. Would you mind share me some information on that, too? Thanks!

Comment: @Bruce no return happens before the first block execution. But, as you've pointed out, many `each`es without a block return an `Enumerator`. This is done explicitly: if no block is given, construct an `Enumerator` with context to reproduce that `each`: an object, an iterator method and its arguments. Try that in irb: `e = 1.upto(5)`. Inspect `e`.

Comment: So this might be one of the differences between statically and dynamically typed languages. So if I understand it correctly, no type inference will happen before the first block execution. If no block is given AND a construction of Enumerator is given, then returns the value of Enumerator type; else if the block is given, run into the block and infer the type of last expression for my_each. So what is the last expression for my_each?

Comment: @Brude I edited the answer to reflect the nature of `Enumerator`s.

Comment: @Bruce, again, think of a block as an argument, a some sort of anonymous function. Methods with blocks return something as well. In case of `scan` it is the original string it processed. If a block is present, in my example this will be the last expression. Otherwise, it will be an Enumerator. Yes, the return type is not clear, but since the difference will only be visible in different usage scenarios, that is for the best.

Comment: Let's put it this way: in my_each, the class method, is its return type (1) a block, (2) the return type of yield expression inside of the block, (3) Object, or (4) something else?

Comment: @Bruce Fine, let's go step by step. It's an **instance** method, first of all. The first version of `my_each` you have in your question, only returns (4) a string. Because the last expression is a call to `scan`, that returns a string.

Comment: I see. So, because the scan in my_each is provided a block (no matter there is a yield or not in that block), its return type should be string, which is the type of the original receiver who calls scan. Right? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Bruce Yes, that's right, its return type is a string regardless of `yield`. However, if `yield` is present but cannot proceed (no block to call) the function just breaks apart, throws an error and halts without returning anything (like after an exception, I don't know much about that yet). A good way of fixing this is described above.

Answer (score 1):

Since a block is given to `scan`, the original string is returned. It does not matter what is done inside the block.

Comment: I know that t.my_each {block} eventually will return the original string, but I was asking what about the my_each itself? I mean, before a block is given to it.

Comment: `my_each` is evaluated together with and depending on its arguments and the potential block. There is no such thing as evaluation of **`my_each` before a block is given**.

Comment: That is exactly the confusing part. So this means Ruby allows in class method implementation "partially valid" code? As my_each itself is not specifying any arguments, nor did it enforce to use the implicit last argument (&block), then the users of that class method have to know the implementation details (there is a "yield") before he can use the method correctly? That doesn't sound like a good design for encapsulation reasons.

Answer (score 1):

`"abcdeabcabc".scan("a") {|x| yield x}`

In the above case, `#scan` is passing the *each matched character to the block* associated to it.

Now inside the block of `#scan`, you are calling `yield`, which actually then calling the block you passed to the method `my_each`. Value of `x` is passed to the block you passed with the method `my_each` call.

It is too simple, no confusions.

> what is the return value of the my_each method of Test class?

As per your current code, the *return value* should be the `#scan` method return value, which in turn causes the result of the *last statement* of the block associated with the method `#my_each` (if called) or the *receiver* on which you called the method `#scan`.

> Is that a list of yield's or something?

Yes, `yield` will be called, as many matches will be found by the `#scan` method.

Consider the below example :-

```
"abcdeabcabc".scan("w") {|x| yield x}
```

Here the *block* associated with the method `#scan` will not be called, as `#scan` didn't find any match, that's why `yield` wouldn't be called also and as a result method `#my_each` wouldn't output block expression(passed with the method) result, but `"abcdeabcabc"`.

Comment: Thanks for the procedural description. Maybe because I just switched from a background of Java-like languages, I get stuck on the return value as Ruby claims every method call returns something. The part I got confused is what the call of my_each returns. Like the "each", [1, 2, 4, 5].each returns an enumerator if no block is given. Here how about the "my_each"? What does it return if no block is given? Or it is simple invalid, for some reason?

Comment: Cool, I see your update now. Your last example is interesting and thanks for that. In the middle you said "yes, yield will be called...", but is that still a list of yields? What type would that "list of yields" be? Since Ruby is dynamically typed I would be interested in what type Ruby will infer on the return of "abcdeabcabc".scan("a") {|x| yield x}